# Send a video file from client to server and back

Tags: java, sockets, video, server

What I basically want is a simple video file transfer: when I press a button the client will send the file to the server and then the server sends the file back again to the client.

What I got now is just send from client to server and server receives it.

Here's some code to begin with :

Client :

```
System.out.println("Connecting...");
sock = new Socket(IP, PORT);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("FILE PATH"));
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

OutputStream stream = sock.getOutputStream();

int count = is.read(bytes, 0, 1024);
while (count != -1) {
    stream.write(bytes, 0, 1024);

    count = is.read(bytes, 0, 1024);
}                         
is.close();
stream.close();                                 
sock.close();
System.out.println("2");
```

Server:

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int count = fin.getInputStream().read(data, 0, 1024);
System.out.println("Receiving video...");
File video = new File("test.mp4");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(video);

while (count != -1) {
    fos.write(data, 0, count);
    count = fin.getInputStream().read(data, 0, 1024);
}
fos.close();
fin.close();
System.out.println("Done receiving");
```

Thanks.

Comment: And what specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm having trouble with starting the code. I can't think of a way to actually write it so. Everytime i try i end up getting no response from the server. I Simply just want the server to response back with the video after the client sent the video.

Comment: You need to use [ServerSockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) for the server.